How to create a 2factor authentication requirement for all users
How can I allow a user a first logins to be without authenticator and then later on move them to a required 2 factor authenticator? Is it only possible with groups that need to be managed or is there something smart that we can do?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
